# Why does index.html.bak take precedence over index.php (Apache)?

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, php

I stumbled upon a strange behavior on my new virtual Debian 11 install.
Under user/public_html I was doing some changes to a page and at some point my browsers started downloading the index file instead of rendering it.

It took quite a while before I realized that the issue was index.html.bak file. This was the file which was being downloaded even though I had index.php in the folder.

I have tested this by setting DirectoryIndex in configs and .htaccess and I can always replicate the issue whenever index.html is set before index.php, and if DirectoryIndex is not set. Index.html.bak is always served before index.php. If index.php is set first in DirectoryIndex, then index.php is served correctly.

Strange thing is that this only happens under public_html, not under /var/www

I can't replicate this on my old Debian server with older Apache.

Is this a bug or do I possibly have some faulty configs? I have barely touched any of the configs since this fresh install.

Apache version is
`Server version: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) Server built: 2022-06-09T04:26:43`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Apache Module `mod_mime`

Please review your Apache `mod_mime` settings and the [Apache 2.4 `mod_mime` Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html).  In particular your `MultiviewsMatch` directive settings and the [associated documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#multiviewsmatch).

Note the following warning excerpted from same:  allowing ***"`Any` extensions to match, even if `mod_mime` doesn't recognize the extension"*** can cause ***"unpredictable results, such as serving `.old` or `.bak` files the webmaster never expected to be served."***

> **Apache Module `mod_mime`**
> This module is used to assign content metadata to the content selected for an HTTP response ***by mapping patterns in the URI or filenames to the metadata values***. For example, the filename extensions of content files often define the content's Internet media type, language, character set, and content-encoding. This information is sent in HTTP messages containing that content and used in content negotiation when selecting alternatives, such that the user's preferences are respected when choosing one of several possible contents to serve. See [mod_negotiation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html) for more information about [content negotiation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html).

##### Files with Multiple Extensions

> Files can have more than one extension; the order of the extensions is *normally* irrelevant. For example, if the file **welcome.html.fr** maps onto content type text/html and language French then the file **welcome.fr.html** will map onto exactly the same information.

> If you would prefer only the last dot-separated part of the filename to be mapped to a particular piece of meta-data, then do not use the *Add* directives.

##### `MultiviewsMatch` Directive

> [// apache.org > 2.4 > mod_mime > multiviewsmatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#multiviewsmatch)
>
> `MultiviewsMatch` permits three different behaviors for [mod_negotiation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html)'s Multiviews feature: `Any`   `NegotiatedOnly`   `Filters|Handlers` *[Handlers|Filters]*

> Multiviews allows a request for a file, e.g. `index.html`, to match any negotiated extensions following the base request, e.g. `index.html.en`, `index.html.fr`, or `index.html.gz`.
>
> The `NegotiatedOnly` option provides that every extension following the base name must correlate to a recognized `mod_mime` extension for content negotiation, e.g. Charset, Content-Type, Language, or Encoding. This is the strictest implementation with the fewest unexpected side effects, and is the default behavior.

> To include extensions associated with `Handlers` and/or `Filters`, set the `MultiviewsMatch` directive to either Handlers, Filters, or both option keywords.

> You may finally allow `Any` extensions to match, even if `mod_mime` doesn't recognize the extension. This can cause unpredictable results, such as serving `.old` or `.bak` files the webmaster never expected to be served.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user [Blind Spots' answer](https://superuser.com/a/1758159/) I was able to solve this mystery (mostly at least) and implement a suitable configuration.

Answers to all my original questions:

If `DirectoryIndex` has index.html ordered before index.php, Apache will first prioritize index.html, then alternate versions of index.html (eg. index.html.bak), before serving index.php if they are absent.

In my Apache mods-enabled/userdir.conf, `Options MultiViews` was already set by default. This option enables the use of `MultiviewsMatch` directive which enables serving alternative files like foo.html.fr.

In my Apache main config apache2.conf, `Options MultiViews` option was NOT enabled by default for /var/www, so that's why the behavior in question was happening only under users' public_html sites.

I don't know why this default setting is different for these two.

For .bak files mime type `application/x-trash` is set by default in Debian. This is why browsers download the .html.bak files instead of rendering them.

There is some inconsistency between what I noted in Apache on my Debian-based system and the Apache documentation:

[apache docs mod_mime.html#multiviewsmatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#multiviewsmatch)

> You may finally allow Any extensions to match, even if mod_mime doesn't recognize the extension. This can cause unpredictable results, such as serving .old or .bak files the webmaster never expected to be served.

In fact .old and .bak files are served even when `MultiviewsMatch NegotiatedOnly` is configured. Those file extensions are assigned `application/x-trash` mime type in /etc/mime.types on Debian. For me this behavior does not make much sense and it also contradicts the documentation, so in a way this is actually a bug.

Now, if you do not want to disable `Multiviews` completely but want to disable serving some known file types, you can remove their mime types from apache in mods-enabled/mime.conf using e.g. `RemoveType bak` and using `MultiviewsMatch NegotiatedOnly`.

Comment: Excellent answer +10. Well written. I suggested some minor edits. I would suggest that the inconsistency you noted warrants a seperate question as, if not a bug, having it answered would add to our understanding. *".old and .bak files served even though MultiviewsMatch `NegotiatedOnly` is configured"*.